# Disable a parent page when a RadWindow opens

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

When i open a Radwindow i would like the parent page to be disabled. The user shoudn't be able to do anything on this page if the radWindow is open.

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager ID="RadWindowManager1" runat="server" EnableShadow="true">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="RadWindow1" runat="server" Width="550px" Height="570px" Title="Nouveau ticket"
            Skin="Windows7" Behaviors="Close, Move" >
        </telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

This is the code i'm using.
I hope you see what i'm looking for.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RadWindow` has a property "Modal".  Set `Modal="True"` on the control to disable the parent page.